# How to exclude posts with empty and non-existent relational custom field with meta_query?

Tags: functions, custom-field, get-posts, meta-query

I have a (category) relation custom field (ACF) in my posts called `im_featured_on_category_pages` -- basically it allows an admin to select if the post should be "featured" on the selected category pages. The stored value is a serialized array like `a:1:{i:0;s:3:"273";}` where '273' would be a "featured" category ID.

In a function called `get_category_featured($catID)` inside my `functions.php` file, I have a function with the following `get_posts` query:

`$cat_featured_posts = get_posts([
    'numberposts' => 3,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category' => $catID,
    'meta_query' => [
        'relation' => 'AND',
        [
            'key' => 'im_featured_on_category_pages',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        ],
        [
            'key' => 'im_featured_on_category_pages',
            'value' => '',
            'compare' => '!='
        ],
        [
            'key' => 'im_featured_on_category_pages',
            'value' => '"' . $catID . '"',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ]
    ],
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC'
]);`

This query works...it only gets 3 posts within that category...but...the meta_query is seemingly ignored. It still returns all posts whether or not the ACF field exists, is empty, or has the correct value I'm looking for.

Basically I want the returned posts to be:

1. In the category provided (`$catID`)
2. Must have a field called `im_featured_on_category_pages`
3. `im_featured_on_category_pages` must not be empty
4. `im_featured_on_category_pages` must contain ('LIKE') the `$catID`
5. The 3 posts returned must be ordered by date (newest first)

Any help at this point would be greatly appreciated...been at this for about 8 hours and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

**UPDATE:** So I've tried several different queries, and no matter what I put in the `meta_query`...it seems to be ignored...I even took the meta_query out and am getting the same result without it. It's like `get_posts()` is completely ignoring my meta_query. Does that have anything to do with the fact that I'm using it in `functions.php` and not in a template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys...I actually inherited this install from someone else. The problem was a plugin (BEEP, https://wordpress.org/plugins-wp/brilliant-easy-exclude-posts/ )...It was causing my meta_queries not to work at all. I'm going to file a report with the plugin folks.